# packaging spring boot application with oracle as database

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

i am trying to package my spring boot application so that i can deploy it on tomcat server. after watching a youtube video i extended SpringBootServletInitializer class and made some changes.

```
 @ComponentScan("com.infodev.loksewa")
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class LoksewaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoksewaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(LoksewaApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**pox.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.infodev</groupId>
    <artifactId>loksewa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>loksewa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>psclockunlock</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

pom.xml would fail to auto import the ojdbc jar file so i added that jar file manually like this:-

[image]

when i run the application on my IDE (Intellij Idea) it runs successfully. but now i need to package it as war file and deploy it on my tomcat server. so when i do package from intellij i get an error which says driver could no be loaded.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

where should i place this ojdbc jar file while packaging the application?

Comment: What did you do in the `pom.xml` to add the jar to the project? You presumably need to add that library to [your repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project).

Comment: check my pom.xml please

Comment: So the answer is nothing - you have done nothing to tell Maven about your dependency and you are surprised that Maven doesn't find it?

Comment: so how do i do that ?

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle) on how to configure yout fat jar with Tomcat using an Oracle driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to Oracle license restrictions, the Oracle JDBC driver is not available in the public Maven repository. To use the Oracle JDBC driver with Maven, you have to download and install it manually into your Maven local repository. To install your Oracle jdbc driver, issue following command :

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc.jar}
>   -DgroupId=com.oracle
>   -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar

add ojdbc6 dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this is actually the correct answer.

Comment: It is if you're building a toy project for yourself. It isn't if you are doing anything more serious, that requires a build server. To be honest, even a toy project for yourself should be done using CI/CD techniques @sagarlimbu

Comment: it is learning purpose project and i am not completely aware of CI/CD techniques.

Comment: thank you sir you saved me great answer